# Proving $f(x)=(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x)))$ is not closed and is the quotient mapping

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

> $S^1$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of all $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $d(y,0)=1$, where $d$ is the Eucledian metric. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to S^{1}$ be given by $f(x)=(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x)))$. Show that $f$ is the quotient mapping but not a closed mapping. Is $f$ an open mapping?

I have no idea on how to solve this question. A closed set in $S_1$ is by the definition of subspace topological space the intersection of a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I cannot see how I can relate all these concepts to the quotient topology.

**Question:**

Can someone help me solve this question?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What does “$f$ is the quotient mapping” mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It is the surjective mapping between one topological space and other topological space, the latter endowed with the quotient topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a closed map, because$$S=\left\{n+\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}\right\}$$is closed, but $f(S)$ isn't ($(1,0)\in\overline{f(S)}\setminus f(S)$).

Comment: How do you conclude that $f(S)$ is not in $(1,0)$ and even if it is not. How can the distance surpass $1$ if $c^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$?

Comment: I understood **nothing** from your questions.

Comment: How do you know that $f(S)$ is not in $(1,0)$? Why (1,0)? If f(S)=(-1,0) then the distance to the origin (0,0) does not surpass $1$.

Comment: I did **not** write that $f(S)$ is not in $(1,0)$. It doesn't make sense! What I wrote was that $S$ is closed by $f(S)$ isn't.. And I proved that assertion using the fact that $(1,0)\in\overline{f(S)}\setminus f(S)$.

Comment: Finally I understood your argument! Thanks! However regarding the fact $f$ is a quotient mapping it is obvious $f$ is surjective and  continuous. But to conclude I would need to show $f$ is open mapping. How should I prove that for any arbitrary interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Take $(a,b)\subset\mathbb R$. If $b-a>1$, then $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)=S^1$, which is an open subset of $S^1$. Otherwise, $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)$ is just an arc in $S^1$ (without endpoints), which is again an open subset of $S^1$.